# A generously vertex transitive graph which is not Cayley?

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs

A graph is *vertex transitive* if $x \mapsto y$ by an automorphism.

A graph is *generously vertex transitive* if $x \mapsto y \mapsto x$ by an automorphism.

Simple facts:

- GVT $\rightarrow$ unimodular. Just plug in the definition of unimodular to see why.
- Cayley $\not \rightarrow$ GVT. Free product $\mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_3$ is an example.
- GVT $\not \rightarrow$ Cayley. Petersen graph is a finite example.

Question:
**Is there an infinite generously vertex transitive connected graph with finite degree which is not a Cayley graph?**

(Before edition, it was also asked: "Is there a common name for this property?", answered by Chris Godsil in the comments.)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you assume your graph to be connected? Otherwise, to answer your first question, you could take infinitely many copies of the Petersen graph.

Comment: Perhaps you want to assume the graph has finite valence? Otherwise, the first question is answered by the complement of @ErikRijcken's example.

Comment: A permutation group $G$ on a set $V$ is _generously transitive_ if, for each pair of points from $F$, there is an element of $G$ that swaps them. The literature I am aware of focusses on the finite case.

Comment: "For the last claim...." But no claims are made. What do you mean?

Comment: I think the OP means "For the last fact..."

Comment: Thank you all for feedback. Question has been edited to remove some of these obscurities.

Comment: Remark: if $X$ is such a graph and $G$ is its automorphism group (with a fixed left Haar measure), any two vertex stabilizers are conjugate by some element $g$ whose square fixes a vertex. In particular, $g$ belongs to a compact subgroup and hence $\Delta(g)=1$; thus all vertex stabilizers have the same Haar measure. Thus $G$ is unimodular. (While there exist many vertex-transitive finite degree connected graph with non-unimodular automorphism group.)

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the comment and for editing the question! I'm not quite sure what you are trying to prove in your comment. Are you justifying that GVT implies unimodular?

Comment: @user334639 Oh, indeed my comment I forgot to write what I meant... the claim is that the group $G$ (which is a locally compact topological group under the pointwise convergence topology) is unimodular. And it also works for the closure in $G$ of every generously vertex-transitive subgroup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the graph product $G = P \times \mathbb{Z}$ of the Petersen graph with the infinite path graph. This is clearly infinite, finite-degree, and generously vertex-transitive.

Then we have two distinguishable types of edge, namely $P$-edges (ones which belong to $5$-cycles) and $\mathbb{Z}$-edges (ones which do not). This means that the automorphisms of $G$ must preserve the obvious product structure, and can uniquely be written as compositions of automorphisms of $P$ with automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$.

If $G$ were a Cayley graph of some group $H$, then there are three generators corresponding to $P$-edges and two corresponding to $\mathbb{Z}$-edges. The actions of the $P$-generators and $\mathbb{Z}$-generators must, respectively, preserve the $\mathbb{Z}$-coordinate and $P$-coordinate of each vertex.

Hence the $P$-generators and $\mathbb{Z}$-generators each generate disjoint normal subgroups of $H$ (and $H$ is their internal direct product). The normal subgroup generated by the $P$-generators is sharply vertex-transitive on $P$, implying that the Petersen graph is a Cayley graph.

Contradiction.

So $G$ has all the properties you requested.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that any distance-transitive graph satisfies your condition (of course, distance-transitivity is much stronger), and you can find many examples (both finite and infinite) in [Peter Cameron's nice paper.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82631488.pdf) (A census of infinite distance-transitive graphs, Discrete Math, 1998) Many of these are not Cayley graphs, it would appear.

Comment: Thanks! Were you able to find a specific example there?

Comment: Most of the examples are not Cayley - check them out.